# The SelectionKey.attach() method

Tags: java, nio

Please give me the concept of the atach() method. Could I work with NIO without atach() method?.

I have read that with this method we can attach any object in a determined SelectionKey, but, I don't find a motive for this, because after registering my SocketChannel within Selector with the READ and WRITE operations, I could read or write toward or from some socket without attaching a buffer, when the Selector tell me that there are read keys, to write I could create a bytebuffer and fill it and write to the socket, and to read I could create a bytebuffer too.

Then, why the programers use atach() method when they register their channels with READ or WRITE operations?

```
SocketChannel cliente=SocketChannel.open(localhost); 
cliente.configureBlocking(false);
Selector selector=Selector.open();
SelectionKey key=cliente.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
//the programers ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(100); key.attach(buf);            

...............................
...............................

selector.select();
Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys=selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator =readyKeys.iterator();                

while(iterator.hasNext()){                    
        SelectionKey key2=iterator.next();                    
        iterator.remove();
        if(key2.isReadable()){
            SocketChannel cliente2=(SocketChannel)key2.channel();
            ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(100) //The programers: ByteBuffer buf2=(ByteBuffer)                    
                                                    //key2.attachment();
            cliente.read(buf);
        }
        if(key2.isWritable()){
            SocketChannel cliente2=(SocketChannel)key2.channel();
            ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(100) //The programers: ByteBuffer buf2=(ByteBuffer)                    
                                                    //key2.attachment();
            buf2.put("Hello Server".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cliente2.write(buf2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> please only give me the concept of the atach() method

There is no `atach()` method. There is however an [`attach()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#attach(java.lang.Object)): "Attaches the given object to this key. An attached object may later be retrieved via the attachment method. Only one object may be attached at a time; invoking this method causes any previous attachment to be discarded. The current attachment may be discarded by attaching null."

> I want to know only that please. Could I work with NIO without atach() method?

Yes, assuming you mean the `attach()` method.

> Indeed thank you for answer my question. I have read that with this method we can attach any object in a determined `SelectionKey`, but, I don't find a motive for this, because after registering my `SocketChannel` within `Selector` with the `READ` and `WRITE` operations, I could read or write toward or from some socket without attaching a buffer, when the `Selector` tell me that there are read keys, to write I could create a bytebuffer and fill it and write to the socket, and to read I could create a bytebuffer too.

You could indeed, and you would be creating a lot of buffers, one per read, when you should be creating one per channel and associating it via the `SelectionKey.attach()` method.

> Then, why the programers use atach() method when they register their channels with READ or WRITE operations?.

To associate some context with the channel. The attachment can be just a buffer, or it can be some kind of context object that contains a buffer, or two, and maybe a session identifier, user credentials, all sorts of things.